# Apply a function over a matrix with matrix subsetting

Tags: r, matrix

I have a numeric matrix `mat` and a logical matrix `ind` of the same size. My goal is very basic: apply a function `fun` columnwise on entries, indicated by `ind`. Here's an example:

```
set.seed(42)
mat <- matrix(1:20, 4)
ind <- matrix(sample(c(F, T), 20, replace = T), 4)
fun <- function(x) sum(x)
```

The "active" subset for `fun` is:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    5    9   13   17
[2,]    2    6   10    .    .
[3,]    .    7    .    .    .
[4,]    4    .   12   16   20
```

My current solution:

```
sapply(1:ncol(mat), function(i) fun(mat[ind[, i], i]))
[1]  7 18 31 29 37
```

It does the job, but I have a feeling I'm missing something very simple and elegant. Any ideas?

Edit: here's another function that does not tolerate extra zeroes, so multiplying `mat * ind` won't work well.

```
fun2 <- function(x) sd(x)
sapply(1:ncol(mat), function(i) fun2(mat[ind[, i], i]))
[1] 1.527525 1.000000 1.527525 2.121320 2.121320
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very easy approach with `tapply`:

```
tapply(mat[ind], col(mat)[ind], fun)
#  1  2  3  4  5 
#  7 18 31 29 37
```

---

Another approach with `mapply`:

```
mapply(function(m, i) fun(m[i]), split(mat, col(mat)), split(ind, col(mat)))
#  1  2  3  4  5 
#  7 18 31 29 37
```

Comment: It only took me half an hour to figure out how this works. Serious magic.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, using apply over columns, while multiplying with the logical matrix should work:

```
> apply(mat*ind,2,fun)
[1]  7 18 31 29 37
```

To better handle FALSE in more general cases (which evaluates to 0 in the multiplication) you could change it to NA and have a function that knows how to handle NAs, e.g.:

```
ind<- ifelse(ind == FALSE, NA, ind)
fun <- function(x) sum(x, na.rm=TRUE)
apply(mat*ind,2,fun)
```

This can be generalized to whatever function you want to apply, with an explicit handling of NAs.

Comment: Good idea. Though in that case `fun` is fed with vectors like (1, 2, 0, 4) instead of (1, 2, 4), which makes no difference for sum, but not for any `fun`.

Comment: yeah, though about that as well and have added a possible solution. It is probably better to transform FALSE -> NA in further processing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
colSums(mat * ind)
#[1]  7 18 31 29 37
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that after I posted it. I guess @fileunderwater's solution in that case will be more helpful for your task?

Comment: Only for functions that treat "zero" like "nothing", unfortunately.

Comment: What abotu NA's? if you do something like `mat[!ind] <- NA` ?

Comment: `fun2 <- function(x) sd(x, na.rm=T); mat[!ind] <- NA` and `apply(mat, 2, fun2)` produce the same output as in your edited question .. not sure if that would be acceptable for your real problem.